# pip not found in Jenkins build

Tags: macos, jenkins, pip, jenkins-pipeline

(I know this question has been asked several times, this post is a result of me trying all previous answers and still failing)

I am trying to build a pipeline in Jenkins. In my Jenkinsfile, I have the stage:

```
stage('Install dependencies') {
        steps {
            echo 'Starting Build'
            sh 'echo $PATH; pip3 install -r requirements.txt'    
        }
    }
```

This stage keeps failing with logs:

```
[2020-06-12T16:02:29.457Z] + PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin:/usr/local/bin
[2020-06-12T16:02:29.457Z] + pip3 install -r requirements.txt
[2020-06-12T16:02:29.457Z] /var/jenkins_home/workspace/CD4MLScenarios_master@tmp/durable-e59fe630/script.sh: 
line 1: pip3: not found
script returned exit code 127
```

I've tried many different things that all end with the same exact error:

- tried adding `sudo easy_install pip3`
- tried adding `withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"])`
- tried adding `PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin;`

When I try `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the error:

```
[2020-06-12T16:55:33.239Z] + python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
[2020-06-12T16:55:33.239Z] /var/jenkins_home/workspace/CD4M-Scenarios_master@tmp/durable-9c155103/script.sh: 
line 1: python3: not found
script returned exit code 127
```

If this is useful at all, this is my docker command I used to start my Jenkins container:

```
docker container run --name jenkins-tutorial --rm --detach   
--network jenkins 
--env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376   
--env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client -
-env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1   
--volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home  
--volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro  
--volume "$HOME":/home --publish 8080:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Comment: is `pip` installed on that system? How about Python? You could try `python3 -mpip install -r requirements.txt` probably

Comment: @AdamSmith I dont understand why trying `sudo easy_install pip3` wouldn't work, then?

Comment: @AdamSmith I did try this and now I get `python3: not found`

Comment: is _python_ installed? Run `python -V`

Comment: @AdamSmith so I dont understand why I have to install python within Jenkins, perhaps someone could explain what is actually going on inside a Jenkins container that makes it so different than what Is happening within my local computer which has python installed?

Comment: in production environments, is not recommended to use jenkins as container. please execute this inside of your jenkins container : `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` to list all users and in your jenkins, run a simple shell `whoami` to detect which user is used by jenkins!

Comment: @datasciencephl why wouldn't you have to install Python within your docker agent? Even on your local computer you can't run software that isn't installed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running Jenkins in a container. Jenkins container does not have `python` installed because it's not needed in order to run Jenkins, and containers by design only include the minimal necessary things.

Moreover, you are running your job on Jenkins master, so it runs in the same place as Jenkins (Jenkins container), so no `python` and no `pip` and no `easy_install`.

You should run your job somewhere where `python` and `pip` are installed. You may want to consider running the job in the `python` container, e.g. like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'python:3' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'pip --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will run a new container (official python3 release container) and execute the steps inside that container.